# (Pre)supply variables to function factory and within

Tags: r

I'm reading through Hadley's [Advanced R](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/) and trying some stuff out.  I'm trying to create a `lazy` closure function that returns a function with the supplied `data.frame` in its environment as well as using `with` and being able to supply additional function arguments later.

```
lazy <- function(dataframe, x) {
    function(FUN, x, ...) {
        with(dataframe, FUN(x = x, ...))
    }
}

lz_factory <- lazy(mtcars, "mpg")

lz_factory(mean)
lz_factory(cor, y="hp")
```

So I was expecting that the dataframe is part of the function environment which it is (a `browser` look see confirms).  However, the variable name `x` is not supply and I can't supply a new variable `y` when I use `cor` as the first `FUN` argument.  This has to do with supplying character to a function (`with`) that uses [non-standard evaluation (NSE)](http://adv-r.had.co.nz/Computing-on-the-language.html#subset).  I want Uncle Hadley to be proud of me but my rummaging with `eval`, `parse`, `substitute` all returned errors.  That means I don't fully get how R is handling things.  I know why it doesn't work (NSE) but not how to make it work.  Here's the errors:

```
> lz_factory(mean)
Error in FUN(x = x, ...) : argument "x" is missing, with no default

> lz_factory(cor, y="hp")
Error in is.data.frame(x) : argument "x" is missing, with no default
```

I thought I could tackle it using substitute as Hadley shows HERE with `xyplot` but that was a flop too as seen here:

```
lazy <- function(dataframe, default) {
    function(FUN, x, ...) {
        if (missing(x)) x <- default
        eval(substitute(with(dataframe, FUN(x, ...))))
    }
}

lz_factory <- lazy(mtcars, "mpg")

lz_factory(mean)
lz_factory(cor, y="hp")


> lz_factory(mean)
[1] NA
Warning message:
In mean.default("mpg") : argument is not numeric or logical: returning NA

> lz_factory(cor, y="hp")
Error in cor("mpg", y = "hp") : 'x' must be numeric
```

So how can I make this lazy function work so it:

1. Produces its own function with the dataframe enclosed in the environment
2. Allows me to supply x if I want and if not uses the default originally supplied
3. Allows me to pass unknown variables to function created by `lz_factory`

Optimally I'd like to make this function work with `with`.  If that's not possible it's be nice to know why.  And lastly if not possible to use `with` how can I make the function operational?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

How about this function

```
lazy <- function(dataframe, ...) {
    pdots <- substitute(list(...))
    if(is.null(names(pdots)) || names(pdots)[1]=="") {
        names(pdots)[2]<-"x"
    }
    function(FUN, ...) {
        dots <- substitute(list(...))[-1]
        if (is.null(dots$x)) {
            dots$x <- pdots$x
        }
        with(dataframe, do.call(FUN, as.list(dots)))
    }
}
```

This allows you to use the names of the variables in mtcars without quotes. For example

```
lz_factory <- lazy(mtcars, mpg)
lz_factory(mean)
# [1] 20.09062
lz_factory(mean, x=hp)
# [1] 146.6875
lz_factory(cor, y=hp)
# [1] -0.7761684
```

Here we use an extra bit of substituting to make sure we get lazy evaluation and to allow you to use the variable names without quotes. The `with` will take care of evaluating the expressions. I'm guessing there may be a way to simplify this, but at least it seems to work.

Comment: Holy smokes more complicated than I thought.  I feel less bad about not getting it.  Very cool.  I'll hold the check for a bit if someone has a different approach.  I understand your approach but, currently, would not have arrived there on my own.

Comment: @Tyler, well I may have over complicated it. I didn't spend a whole lot of time trying to reduce it. Also, wasn't sure if you really wanted to pass the column names as strings or not. That may change some of the `substitute` calls to `get` calls. Because even in `with`, you can't use strings as variable names.

Answer (score 5):

Here's a slightly simplified version of @MrFlick's function:

```
lazy <- function(df, x_var = NULL) {
  x <- substitute(x_var)

  function(FUN, ...) {
    call <- substitute(FUN(...))
    if (is.null(call$x) && !is.null(x)) {
      call$x <- x
    }
    eval(call, df, parent.frame())
  }
}
```

The key is taking greater advantage of the capabilities of `substitute()`, and avoiding `with()` by using eval directly.

Comment: Thanks for your thinking.  I appreciate it tons and have been enjoying and learning a ton from Advanced R